# The thing that holds the mirror was partially broken, can it still be fixed?

Tags: nikon, camera, mirror

The thing that holds the mirror has been broken and now I’m taking shots of pure white, what can you suggest? Please, can it still be fixed?

Comment: As already mentioned, fixing this would be more expensive than buying a replacement camera.